# Adding readonly attribute to all form elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm using jQuery to add a readonly attribute to all form elements but can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$('#form1').each( function() { $(this).attr('readonly', true); });
```

I have a simple form using label/input to display form elements.
Also I'm using [tipsy](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy) (Tool tip plug-in) as well as [Formalize](http://sonspring.com/journal/formalize-css) (Look and Feel Plug-in)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#form1 input').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

- You may want to include more elements `#form1 input, #form1 textarea, #form1 select`
- In jQuery, you usually don't need to iterate over the collection. `attr` would work for a collection same as for a single element.
- In your case, `#form1` matched just the `<form>` element, and `each` was triggered *once*, for that element. To find *all* elements (input or not), you can write `#form1 *`.

Comment: just a technicality, but "attr('readonly', true)" is better than "attr('readonly', 'readonly'). jQuery's "attr()" method operates on DOM properties, not actual HTML attributes, and the property value for "readonly" must be either "true" or "false". It just so happens that 'readonly' casts to true in javascript, but it's better to include the boolean to start with.

Comment: @Phill, how *precisely* is it not working for you? Does it do nothing at all? Return a js error? Something else?

Comment: @Ben Lee, I'm using FireBug console and I see no execution errors, viewing the source I don't the readonly="readonly" applied to any of the input elements in form1

Comment: @Phil - look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8vSKR/ . Try posting some more code so we can help `:)`

Comment: problem was it was outside of the document.ready scope, placed the code inside and works great. Thanks

Comment: Just one note, as input radio doesn't accept "readonly" attribute, with this kind of element you must use this: $('#form1 input[type=radio]').attr('disabled', true)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891734/setting-a-control-to-readonly-using-jquery-1-6-prop#answer-5891833 the readonly portion is case sensitive and should be 'readOnly'

Comment: @CamHart - Is that documented? As far as I know jQuery deals with that: [`prop`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9adfad19865837f5dffedb1eb41e407f196ca515/src/attributes/prop.js#L84-L97), [`attr`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9adfad19865837f5dffedb1eb41e407f196ca515/src/attributes/attr.js#L39) . Either way, this answer is a little dated, but the test is working, as far as I see: http://jsfiddle.net/8vSKR/

Answer (score 42):

This is even better use the [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). Also note Read only is only for input type of text and password and textarea . It will not work on select elements, radio, checkboxes, buttons. If you want to display but not allow them to type or click. Try using disabled.

```
$("#form1 :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Note: by using disabled it will grey out the input, select or textarea but will not post this element when submitted. If you need it to post let me know and I can help you out.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5PAn/) http://jsfiddle.net/j5PAn/

Comment: @Phil  I wasnt actually finished entering my question... you may want to re-read

Comment: @eXtreme   you would need to serialize all disabled elements and post your serialized data.

Answer (score 5):

To get all elements of form:

```
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(index, value){
    $('[name="' + value.name + '"]').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form>
    <fieldset disabled>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

probably the best way to do that