# Setting a control to readonly using jquery 1.6 .prop()

Tags: jquery, readonly, jquery-1.6

With the release of jQuery 1.6, the recommendation on SO has been to generally start using prop() where you used to use attr().

What happens when I want make an element readonly?

```
$('.control').prop('readonly', 'readonly');
$('.control').prop('readonly', true);
```

Neither of these seem to make the control readonly. Is making an element readonly the exception to the rule?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `prop()` wherever you used `attr()`, just when you want to access a property or a HTML attribute (I think).

Comment: @alex You SHOULD be using `prop()` in many cases, as `attr()` can refer to the original markup attribute value, which may be empty and / or be different to the current value of `prop()` (the property).

Comment: I think he's referring to the comment I made: "start using prop() where you used to use attr()". This is not entirely true - only use it when it's necessary (ie. accessing a property).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that the property name is case-sensitive.  Try:

```
$('.control').prop('readOnly', true);
```

Though really I don't know why this requires jQuery.  This works just as well:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("control")[0].readOnly = true;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the 2nd example you've given, on readability alone. This is probably too obvious to mention, but you didn't seem to take that into consideration in promoting it

Comment: That depends how you measure readability.  The semantics of `$()` and `prop()` are not exactly obvious to people without experience in JavaScript and jQuery.  On the other hand `getElementsByClassName()` pretty much tells you exactly what it does.  There's something to be said in favor of self-documenting code.

Comment: Do you see how much longer the second statement is?  25 characters.  We don't have time for that.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$(".control").prop({ readOnly: true });
```

I think of it like this: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) gets the default value in the html markup while [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) gets/sets the value dynamically.  Look at the following:

```
<input id="someInput" readonly="readOnly" />

$(".control").attr("readOnly") // would yield "readOnly"
$(".control").prop("readOnly") // would yield true
$(".control").is(":readOnly")  // would yield true
```

The api documentation says this:

> The difference between attributes and
>   properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery
>   1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when
>   retrieving some attributes, which
>   could cause inconsistent behavior. As
>   of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method
>   provides a way to explicitly retrieve
>   property values, while .attr() only
>   retrieves attributes.