# how can i set the drop down as readonly in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to set the drop down as readonly. 
For that I user the code `readonly="readonly"`.But its not working in asp.netmvc4.How can I solve this problem?Please help

Comment: @Agent1 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100351/how-to-make-a-dropdown-readonly-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100351/how-to-make-a-dropdown-readonly-using-jquery) Here you can find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in jQuery

```
$('#id').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: @PSR-I don't want disabled.If it is disabled i can't take the value from it

Comment: Now you should use .prop() instead of .attr()

Comment: @Agent1 Well what did you mean then? Drop downs are always read-only..

Comment: is there any possibilities to avoid to select the list.

Answer (score 12):

You can do like this

Make other options disabled except the current one.

```
$('option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9X6df/)

Comment: very useful tip, specially when you have to post your values from protected fields without any hidden fields

$(function () {
    $("select[readonly='readonly'] option:not(:selected)").attr('disabled', true);
});

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via jquery. It saves you from browser compatibility issues too.
jQuery:

```
$('#yourselectid').attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the select element doesn't accept readonly, [W3 spec is here for reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-SELECT).

As others have suggested, your best bet would be to use the disabled 'disabled' attribute instead.