# Making sharepoint List dropdown read-only

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my sharepoint list newform.aspx, I have two cascading dropdown *(Country, Training), where based on the Country, Trainings gets populated. I had achieved this using spservices.

Now for some country users I need to make default country as their own country in dropdown and show its corresponding trainings.

Kindly let me know how can I get this. I'm able to disable dropdown with specific country using jquery. But i want make readonly, because only when the value newform saves to sharepoint list.

Its happen for textbox not for dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this has been answered here:
[How to make a dropdown readonly using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100351/how-to-make-a-dropdown-readonly-using-jquery)

A hidden field is the key.