# Django Set custom field in form not required

Tags: django

ModelAdmin

```
class InstrumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    def get_form(self,request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            return UpdateForm
        else:
            return CreateForm
```

Update Form

```
class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    connector = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Connector.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}), initial='multiplate')

    class Meta:
        model = Instrument
        fields = ['connector','name']
```

I have set initial value for the ChoiceField. But when i access the change of the model and Save, it prompt me "This field is required" for the field connector.

How can I make the field not mandatory in this case? Because it will always have a value there.

Comment: If it will always have a value, then it *is* mandatory, surely?

Comment: Yes, that's the weird part. Can check the photo below.
http://s16.postimg.org/o25nng19h/Capture.png

Comment: If I set Required=False for ModelChoiceField, initial value will be missing.

Comment: Please show the view code.

Comment: I have added ModelAdmin form above. I return UpdateForm if it is Change. In the UpdateForm, I create a new custom field named Connector and set an initial value (the value is existing in the database Connector table)

Comment: Found out one thing. Even if I set initial='', it will show me multiplate also. Huh? What happening.

Answer (score 0):

Fixes:

1. initial=pk instead of name
2. Add required=False

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your attributes.
Change:

```
attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}
```

to

```
attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}
```

Disabled does not send back data to the server while readonly does it.

Comment: Using attrs={'readonly':'readonly'} help in showing data. But the dropdown still able to change using readonly

Comment: The selected answer of this would answer that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100351/how-to-make-a-dropdown-readonly-using-jquery